# ListView of Hardware Resources Memory Info (msinfo32) 

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, memory, ram, system-information

Is there any way to do this in vb.net?

[image]
Are there any functions for retrieving that info?Any way to display theme in a ListView?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some basic information (also not as detailed as in your image) through the `My.Computer.Info` Object.

The following properties give information on your computers the memory

> AvailablePhysicalMemory
>   AvailableVirtualMemory
>   TotalPhysicalMemory
>   TotalVirtualMemory

There is an interesting article on the Code Project about getting information on your PC's hardware: [How To: (Almost) Everything In WMI via C# - Part 3: Hardware](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw). The code is in C#; however, the same approach can be used in VB.

Comment: Yes,I knew about that functions.I'll search further to find if it's possible to do what i want.Thank you.